In js/react, is there an "onClick" but only for the "down/start" events, similar to "onMouseDown"?
In Chrome, "onClick" fires on mouse events, touch events, and keyboard events (such as pressing "enter" when focused"). Conversely, "onMouseDown" and "onTouchStart" both fire only when their respective inputs are pressed.
So, what would happen when I add "onTouchStart" and "onMouseDown" to an element? Then, in laptops with touchscreen monitors, both mouse and touch events are fired because the touchscreen counts both as a mouse AND a touch event. And in the Chrome dev tools when one goes into mobile mode, mouse clicks also count as both mouse clicks and touch events.
What really needs to happen is for there to be something like "onClick" but for the "start" phase of events, not the "release" phase.
This would be trivially easy to do in a game engine like Unity or Godot, but for whatever reason most modern browsers do not allow this.
Does anybody have some insight that could help solve this problem?

It's not JavaScript that's responsible for this, it's the browser and  the DOM specification.

Fair enough, I edited the post to reflect that

Do you mean pointerdown event?

@SanketSapate Almost, but not quite. "pointerDown" would not have accessability features like being able to press enter while focused to click

No, why would you think that?

From what I have researched, there is no event which will behave exactly the way you want.
But you can achieve this by using different events together.
To handle both the "start" phase of events consistently across different input types (mouse, touch, pen) and maintain accessibility (like responding to "Enter" or "Space" key presses), you can use a combination of pointerdown and click events in React.
Here's an example of how you can implement this:
import React from 'react';

const CustomButton = ({ onStart }) => {
  const handlePointerDown = (event) => {
    onStart(event);
  };

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    // Ensure onStart is only called for keyboard events to avoid double-firing
    if (event instanceof KeyboardEvent) {
      onStart(event);
    }
  };

  return (
    <button 
      onPointerDown={handlePointerDown}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      Press Me
    </button>
  );
};

export default CustomButton;

Advantages

Unified Handling: The pointerdown event handles mouse, touch, and pen inputs, simplifying the event handling logic.
Accessibility: click handles keyboard interactions, ensuring users can activate the button using "Enter" or "Space" keys.
Avoids Double-Firing: The check in the handleClick function prevents the onStart function from being called twice for the same interaction.


Very clever answer, cheers

Whoops, it looks like when I went and implemented this the event was still getting fired on mouse release

Can you share some code?

I got it working, I'll also edit the answer:
onClick={(e) => {
if (!(e instanceof KeyboardEvent)) return
handleMute()
}}

I think someone needs to approve the edit for it to be live

Yes, I can't do that.
